# Pandas replace value with other column value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a table and I want to replace column values with other columns values based on a condition:

Table:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | test | fool | bar |
| y | 3 | test | fool | bar |

If column C contains the word test -> value should be replaced with content of column A

If column D contains the word fool -> value should be replaced with content of column B

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| x | 1 | x | 1 | bar |
| y | 3 | y | 3 | bar |

How can I create this table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can use `np.where` here:

```py
df["C"] = np.where(df["C"] == "test", df["A"], df["C"])
df["D"] = np.where(df["D"] == "fool", df["B"], df["D"])
```